# Reinstall Grub, grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub

Windows is install on sdb drive and ubuntu 18.04 on the sda, I'm trying to recover the grub as windows updates removed the grub loader, here is the drives status.

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    485375    483328   236M EFI System
/dev/sda2     485376  33298431  32813056  15.7G Linux swap
/dev/sda3   33298432 130955263  97656832  46.6G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  130955264 468860927 337905664 161.1G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 50C485F0-3276-4B2E-9CB9-9A52C64F27DF

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048     34815     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb2      34816 213399551 213364736 101.8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb3  213399552 500117503 286717952 136.7G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sdc: 15.1 GiB, 16231956480 bytes, 31703040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0005a5bd

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *     2048 31703039 31700992 15.1G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

blkid

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="ADC3-E91C" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="fb9053a7-ae31-4448-9eca-dc8fedf6fee3"
/dev/sda3: UUID="75724aad-9957-44b9-8f94-db27227545c3" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="41716fbf-4d56-4cc7-822f-2083cde39263"
/dev/sda4: UUID="ef014f8c-f8cd-4501-8235-75ead0d5f1cf" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="11343f93-36a6-4c4a-99ae-62a8a942a970"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="M2-1" UUID="b900ddbe-fb05-4b4a-b1a7-9df4f0cb8056" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="3680107f-c7af-460e-a339-f60fd3a65bb5"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="92726A85726A6E43" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="b021d210-4d3d-4bb0-b4ca-9b27bddb34ea"
/dev/sdb3: LABEL="Backup" UUID="D2F6-BCC2" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="8a34f372-f9d8-4bf0-82e1-722e4dc3c8b9"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="UBUNTU 18_0" UUID="C840-3295" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="0005a5bd-01"
```

When I run these commands it raise an error, not sure what to do now.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mkdir /mnt/ubuntu
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/ubuntu
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/ubuntu/boot /dev/sda
 Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

BIOS:
"Legacy Support Enabled and Secure boot disable" option is selected as it was working fine.